# Double free or corruption at end of program with no free's

Tags: c++, debugging, free, glibc

My program is completing and even printing the final "DONE2" just before return 0; in main.
I have dynamic memory allocation with malloc but I have no free's in my program.

Why/how can I get this without free's, why is my program still running until completion, how should I find the source of the error/s ?

Edit: I'm only asking how it would be possible to get the error without free's and how the program would reach the end of execution.

```
*** glibc detected *** ./prog: double free or corruption (out): 0x09574040 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x9ca595]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x59)[0x9ca9d9]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x21)[0x2e6c581]
./prog[0x804b2f9]
./prog[0x804b33b]
./prog[0x804b34f]
./prog[0x804b4d5]
./prog[0x804b4ec]
./prog[0x804bb6f]
./prog[0x8049d43]
./prog[0x8049d59]
./prog[0x8049d88]
./prog[0x8049da2]
./prog[0x8049de3]
./prog[0x8049e6f]
./prog[0x8049604]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xdc)[0x976e9c]
./prog(__gxx_personality_v0+0x79)[0x8049271]
======= Memory map: ========
002d4000-002d5000 r-xp 002d4000 00:00 0          [vdso]
0093e000-00958000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 559505     /lib/ld-2.5.so
00958000-00959000 r-xp 00019000 fd:00 559505     /lib/ld-2.5.so
00959000-0095a000 rwxp 0001a000 fd:00 559505     /lib/ld-2.5.so
00961000-00aa0000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 559506     /lib/libc-2.5.so
00aa0000-00aa2000 r-xp 0013f000 fd:00 559506     /lib/libc-2.5.so
00aa2000-00aa3000 rwxp 00141000 fd:00 559506     /lib/libc-2.5.so
00aa3000-00aa6000 rwxp 00aa3000 00:00 0 
00aa8000-00acd000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 559513     /lib/libm-2.5.so
00acd000-00ace000 r-xp 00024000 fd:00 559513     /lib/libm-2.5.so
00ace000-00acf000 rwxp 00025000 fd:00 559513     /lib/libm-2.5.so
02dab000-02db6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 559517     /lib/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
02db6000-02db7000 rwxp 0000a000 fd:00 559517     /lib/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
02db9000-02e99000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 79091      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
02e99000-02e9d000 r-xp 000df000 fd:00 79091      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
02e9d000-02e9e000 rwxp 000e3000 fd:00 79091      /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
02e9e000-02ea4000 rwxp 02e9e000 00:00 0 
08048000-0805c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 789714     /home/echelon/correngine/prog
0805c000-0805d000 rw-p 00013000 fd:00 789714     /home/echelon/correngine/prog
09553000-09594000 rw-p 09553000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7fa9000-b7fab000 rw-p b7fa9000 00:00 0 
b7fb4000-b7fb5000 rw-p b7fb4000 00:00 0 
bfbe9000-bfbfe000 rw-p bffea000 00:00 0          [stack]
DONE
DONE2
make: *** [run] Aborted
```

Edit: Thanks, the problem was that I overran a buffer by a long shot which caused 'corruption' and not a double free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have dynamic memory allocation with malloc but I have no free's in my program

Whoa! Stop right here! This is a serious problem—a bug in your program. It's not really important to figure out why *other* things aren't working properly when you have this glaring bug. You need to fix this problem *first* by adding a matching call to `free` for each call that you have to `malloc`. Only once you have done this should you worry about solving your *other* problems (if they even still exist)!

> Why/how can I get this without free's

It is almost certain that this is reporting a problem unrelated to the use (or lack of use) of `free`. The important part of the error message is actually the *corruption* part.

It is common to get this error when you are overwriting past the block of memory you asked for using `malloc`. For example, if you meant to allocate a block of memory to hold a structure `Foo`, but you only allocated space for a *pointer* to a structure `Foo`, you will keep on writing beyond the amount of space that was actually allocated, corrupting information in memory that does not belong to you. glibc is detecting this corruption of what is likely its own data in memory and throwing a fit.

It is impossible for us to find out where this is occurring unless we can see the actual code. But when you go over your code searching for all of the calls to `malloc` in order to match them up with a corresponding call to `free`, that's also a good time to check and make sure that each of your calls to `malloc` are correct.

> why is my program still running until completion

If the problem is as I predict above, you've entered into the realm of [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Basically, this means you've done something that the language standard says you should not do (write over memory that does not belong to you). Since you've done it anyway, the language standard provides absolutely no guarantees on what might happen when your program is executed. It *might* work perfectly fine. It *might* crash every time. It *might* crash only sometimes. It *might* corrupt your hard disk. It *might* cause your house to catch on fire and [demons to fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). You just never know. That's why you should avoid invoking Undefined Behavior at all costs. Not only is it scary, it also points to a bug in your code.